# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} x(16x^4 + x^2+1)^{1/4}-2x^2$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Can someone please check my conclusion to the evaluation of the following limit?
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(16x^4 + x^2+1)^{1/4}-2x^2$$

I got that the limit is equal to infinity. If limit is equal to infinity does this mean that limit does not exist?

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion? We cannot check your conclusion without seeing how you got it. Please provide [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960).

Answer (score 3):

$\text{HINT}$

$$x(16x^4 + x^2+1)^{1/4}-2x^2 $$ $$=x^2(16+ \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4})^{1/4}-2x^2$$ $$=x^2(\sqrt[4]{16 + \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}-2)$$ $$=\frac{\sqrt[4]{16 + \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}-2}{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

You can multiply the last fraction with $$\sqrt[4]{16 + \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}+2$$ both numerator and denominator and then you will multiply the resulting fraction with $$\sqrt{16 + \frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}+4$$ both numerator and denominator.

For more convinience with your calculations put $u=\frac{1}{x^2} \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$

So calculate the limit of the function $f(u)$ as $u \to 0$ where $u=\frac{1}{x^2}$

Thus you will get the result $\frac{1}{32}$

Comment: L'Hospital's rule requires derivatives

Comment: can we get to that answer without L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @BellePepper see my edits and try the last hint

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$g(x) = 16x^4 + x^2+1 = 16(x^2 + \frac 1{32})^2 + \frac{63}{64}$$

Take the fourth root to get

$$\sqrt[4]{g} \sim 2 \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1{32}}$$
as $x \to \infty$.

We still have to multiply by $x$ and then subtract $2x^2$. We see that

$$x \cdot 2 \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1{32}} = 2 \sqrt{x^4 + \frac {x^2}{32}} = 2 \sqrt{(x^2 + \frac 1{64})^2 -\frac{1}{4096}}$$

And $$2 \sqrt{(x^2 + \frac 1{64})^2 -\frac{1}{4096}} \sim 2(x^2 + \frac 1{64}) = 2x^2 + \frac 1{32}$$ as $x \to \infty$.

Finally we subtract the $2x^2$ to get $$2x^2 + \frac 1{32}- 2x^2 = \frac 1{32}$$

Hence  $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x \sqrt[4]{16x^4 + x^2+1}-2x^2 = \frac 1{32}$$ which can be verified using L'Hôpital's Rule.

But your follow-up question was important, so I'll answer it as if the limit were infinity.

When we write $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$$ we are saying that for any real number $M$, there is a real number $\delta$ (which will depend on $M$) such that $f(x)\gt M$  for all $x$ such that $0\lt |x| \lt \delta$. It is important to realize, however, that **the limit does not exist. For the limit to exist, it needs to be a number, and $\infty$ is not a number.** The expression "$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$" is just a concise way to express the idea that $f$ increases without bound.

Comment: can we get to that answer without L'Hopital's rule? because I have not studied it yet

Comment: If the limit is infinite, one usually says it and goes along. Why should one say the limit does not exist?

Comment: @egreg If the limit exists, you can say "f approaches L". If the limit exists and the limit is infinity, then you'd have to say "f approaches infinity," but infinity is not a number. When we say the limit is infinity, it's a colloquialism that saves us the trouble of saying "for any real number $M$, there is a real number $\delta$ (which will depend on $M$) such that $f(x)\gt M$  for all $x$ such that $0\lt |x| \lt \delta$."

Comment: @BellePepper I've edited my answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I used "~" to express "is essentially" in a Big-O sense.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is not infinity. If you need to do it the hard way, consider
$$
x(\sqrt[4]{16x^4+x^2+1}-2x)
=x\frac{\sqrt{16x^4+x^2+1}-4x^2}{\sqrt[4]{16x^4+x^2+1}+2x}
=\frac{x(x^2+1)}{(\sqrt[4]{16x^4+x^2+1}+2x)(\sqrt{16x^4+x^2+1}+4x^2)}
=\frac{x^3(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}
 {x^3
  \Bigl(\sqrt[4]{16+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}+2\Bigr)
  \Bigl(\sqrt{16+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}}+4\Bigr)
 }
$$
However, it's much easier with a Taylor expansion. If you substitute $x=1/t$, with easy algebraic manipulations the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt[4]{16+t^2+t^4}-2}{t^2}=
2\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt[4]{1+t^2/16+t^4/16}-1}{t^2}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[4]{1+t^2/16+t^4/16}=1+\frac{1}{4}\frac{t^2}{16}+o(t^2)
$$

---

About the case when the limit is infinity, it depends on the conventions you're following whether the limit “exists”. Check with your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make use of the (not so) popular formula $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x^n-a^n} {x-a} =na^{n-1}\tag{1}$$ Putting $x^{2}=1/t$ we can see that $t\to 0^{+}$ and the expression under limit is transformed into $$2\cdot\frac{(1+t/16+t^2/16)^{1/4}-1}{t}=2\cdot\frac{(1+t/16+t^2/16)^{1/4}-1}{t/16+t^{2}/16}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{t}{16}\right)$$ and therefore the limit is equal to the limit of $$\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{(1+t/16+t^2/16)^{1/4}-1}{t/16+t^{2}/16}$$ as $t\to 0^{+}$. Next we put $u=1+t/16+t^2/16$ so that $u\to 1^{+}$ and the desired limit is equal to $$\frac{1}{8}\lim_{u\to 1^{+}}\frac{u^{1/4}-1^{1/4}}{u-1}$$ which equals $(1/8)(1/4)=1/32$ via formula $(1)$.